# PDO and rowcount

Tags: mysql, pdo, rowcount

I'm trying to make the PDO query below working, but somehow it doesn't.
This is how far i mine brain exploded!
Is there somebody who can say what i'm doint wrong?

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename", "user", "pass");
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `email`=':email' and `name`=':name'");
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', 'mail@mail.nl',PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', 'name',PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute(); 

    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        echo "row count 1";
    }
    else if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0)
    {
        echo "row count 0";
    }
    else if ($stmt->rowCount() > 1)
    {
        echo "row count greater then 1";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote string literals in SQL, so the prevent PDO from parsing inside them. If you want to use bind variables, you should remove the quotes (don't worry, PDO will properly handle them as strings):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare
        ("SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `email`=:email and `name`=:name");
```